# How can I handle overflow data in Html table?

Tags: html, css

I generated following PDF report data formation by HTML using Rotativa.
But when I tested with large data, above the header report is getting cut.
So how can I handle large data in HTML without page margins not affected.

I have used pure `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>` structure to design. And to prevent data to overflow, I have set all my tables with style `table-layout:fixed` and `word-wrap: break-word`.

**normal report view:**

[image]

**altered report view:**

[image]

following is my html page for the header
Does anyone help me?

```
<div id="header" style="font-family: Calibri; padding-top: 25px;">
    <div style="float: right; font-family: Calibri; padding-right: 15px; font-size: 11px; margin-bottom: 2px;">
        Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var vars = {};
            var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            for (var i in x) {
                var z = x[i].split('=', 2); vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
            }
            var p = ['page', 'topage', 'frompage', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection'];
            for (var i in p) {
                var y = document.getElementsByClassName(p[i]);
                for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
                    y[j].textContent = vars[p[i]];
            }
        })();
    </script>

        <table id-="reportHedear" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid lightgrey; font-family: Calibri; top: 10px">
            <tr style="width: 100%">
                <td style="width: 1%" valign="top"></td>
                <td style="width: 75%" valign="top">
                    <table style="width: 100%; margin: 0px; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tr style="width: 100%">
                            <td id="logo" style="width: 25%; margin-top: 10px">
                                <img src="@Model.CompanyLogo" alt="" style="max-height: 50px; max-width: 220px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 3%"></td>
                            <td id="companyHeader" style="width: 72%" valign="top">
                                @if (@Model.CompanyMainTag != null && @Model.CompanyTag1 != null && @Model.CompanyISOTag != null)
                                {
                                    <table style="table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word; width:100%; border-top: 5px solid; border-bottom: 5px solid;">
                                        <tr id="mainTag" style="width:100%">
                                            <td style="width:100%; text-align: center; font-size:15px">@Model.CompanyMainTag</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="tag1" style="width:100%">
                                            <td style="width:100%; text-align: center; font-size:13px">@Model.CompanyTag1</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="companyISO" style="width:100%">
                                            <td style="width:100%; text-align: center; font-size:15px">@Model.CompanyISOTag</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width:100%;">
                            <td colspan="3" style="width:100%; ">
                                <table style="width:100%; font-size: 12px; table-layout: fixed">
                                    <tr style="width:100%">
                                        <td id="addressInfo" style="width: 30%" valign="top">
                                            <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word">
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; text-align: right; font-weight: bold" valign="top"><span>Address: </span></td>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%;"><label>@Model.ComapnyAddress</label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <td style="width: 45%; text-align: right; font-weight: bold" valign="top"><span>Phone: </span></td>
                                                    <td style="width: 55%"><span>@Model.ComapnyPhone</span></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                @if (Model.IsEnableProgramManager)
                                            {
                                                    <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                    <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                        <td style="width: 45%; text-align:right; font-weight: bold" valign="top"><span>Program Manager: </span></td>
                                                        <td style="width: 55%"><span>@Model.ProgramManager</span></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            }

                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="companyDetail" style="width: 35%" valign="top">
                                            <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word">
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right;" valign="top"><span>@Model.CustomerLabel: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%; font-weight: bold"><span>@Model.CompanyName</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right" valign="top"><span>Address: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%;"><label>@Model.Address</label></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right" valign="top"><span>Web: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%"><span>@Model.Website</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="comapnyDetails1" style="width: 35%" valign="top">
                                            <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word">
                                                <tr style="width: 100%;">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right;" valign="top"><span>Attn: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%; "><span>@Model.ContactPersonName</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right" valign="top"><span>Email: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%;"><span>@Model.EmailID</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right" valign="top"><span>Phone: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%"><span>@Model.ContactNo</span></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
                                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                                    <th style="width: 30%; text-align: right" valign="top"><span>Fax: </span></th>
                                                    <td style="width: 70%"><span>@Model.Fax</span></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 2%" valign="top"></td>
                <td style="width: 21%" valign="top">
                    <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed" align="center">
                        <tr style="width: 100%">
                            <td style="width: 100%" align="center">
                                <span style="margin-bottom: 1px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px">@Model.AssemblyQuotationHeader</span>
                                <table id="QuoteDetails" style="max-width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-top: 1px; margin-left: 10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border: black; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">
                                    <tr style="width: 100%">
                                        <td style="max-width: 45%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">RFQ ID</td>
                                        <td style="max-width: 55%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">@Model.QuoteID</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="width: 100%">
                                        <td style="max-width: 45%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">Assembly Id</td>
                                        <td style="max-width: 55%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">@Model.AssemblyIDWithVersion</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="width: 100%">
                                        <td style="max-width: 45%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">Date</td>
                                        <td style="max-width: 55%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">@Model.QuoteDate</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @if (Model.IsEnableQuoteExpirationDate)
                                {
                                        <tr style="width: 100%">
                                            <td style="max-width: 45%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; background-color: lightgray; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">Expires</td>
                                            <td style="max-width: 55%; font-size: 15px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom: 3px; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">@Model.ExpireDate</td>
                                        </tr>
                                }

                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width: 100%">
                            <td style="width: 100%; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
                                <p>@Model.AssemblyQuotationMsg</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 1%"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Just set the CSS overflow property on the element that it is within

Comment: is the pdf header height fixed?

Comment: nope. pdf header is not fixed. just given width: 100%. And @ Cristophs0n : overflow is not working here

Comment: I'd be surprised if applying `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; ` and a `width` didn't work. Can you provide a plunker or codepen

Comment: As I am new in stackoverflow, cant provide plunker. I need text wrap in some <td> as address informations are coming in it so I have set word-wrap: break-word

Comment: `<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%; border-top: 5px solid;border-bottom: 5px solid;">`
                                        `<tr id="mainTag" style="width:100%">`
                                           ` <td style="width:100%; text-align: center; font-size:15px">@Model.CompanyMainTag dfsdfdsf sdf dfs dsfdsf dsfd sfdf dfdsf dsfdfwecvcv dgfdgfsgsf sf sfsdfdsfds</td>`
                                       ` </tr></table>`

Comment: No one knows the solution?